# Customizing __instancecheck__ in python

Tags: python

Why is this printing a False?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

class A(object):
    def __instancecheck__(self,arg):
        print self, type(self), arg , type(arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    print isinstance(a,a)
```

Gives:

```
$ ./isinstancecheck.py 
<__main__.A object at 0x7f0574198b90> <class '__main__.A'> <__main__.A object at     0x7f0574198b90> <class '__main__.A'>
False
```

Comment: Due to the Python specification, overriding `__instancecheck__` does not seem to work in some cases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168971/instancecheck-overwrite-shows-no-effect-what-am-i-doing-wrong

Answer (score 5):

The `__instancecheck__` magic should be defined on the *metaclass*, not on the class itself.  See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks):

> Note that these methods are looked up on the type (metaclass) of a class. They cannot be defined as class methods in the actual class.

The curious behavior you're seeing is by misplacing the `isinstance` arguments. You wrote:

```
isinstance(a, a)
```

But it should really be:

```
isinstance(a, A)
```

Now, here's the comedy of errors: if you've mistakenly defined `__instancecheck__` as a method on a normal class, *instances* of the class can accidentally be used as the *second* argument of `isinstance` (normally the second arg would be the class object). Python doesn't really care if the second argument's type is a class or a metaclass, because that's just duck-typing in action.

Note that `isinstance` coerces the return value of `__instancecheck__` to boolean. Invoking directly with `a.__instancecheck__(a)` will return the `None`.

Comment: It's worth noting that for correct usage `isinstance(a, A)` the `__instancecheck__` won't be called since it's an exact type match and so a shortcut is taken (see [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue35083)).

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks), `__instancecheck__` should return True or False.

But, `A.__instancecheck__` in your code does return Nothing; None is returned implicitly; `None` is treated as False; so the `False` is printed.

Comment: `print None` prints "None". I do not think that's what is happening here.

Comment: @abc, You're not calling `__instancecheck__` directly. (It is called internally by `isinstance`). Add `return True` at the end of `__instancecheck__`, then try `print isinstance(a, ...)`.

Comment: @abc `isinstance` coerces the result of `__instancecheck__` to bool.

Comment: What you answered is not strictly *wrong*, but it's not really the heart of the problem either.  Correct usage is `isinstance(a, A)` with the hook defined on the *metaclass*.  This answer is pretty confused!