# __instancecheck__ - overwrite shows no effect - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass, magic-methods, isinstance

I'm trying to make my class appear as a different object to circumvent lazy type checking in a package I'm using. More specifically, I'm trying to make my object appear as an instance of another object (`tuple` in my case) when in reality it is not even a derivation of that.

In order to achieve this, I plan to overwrite the `__isinstance__` method which, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#class.__instancecheck__), should do exactly what I desire. However, it appears that I didn't understand how do to do that exactly, because my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Here's an SSCCE that *should* make `isinstance` return `False` in all cases but doesn't.

```
class FalseInstance(type):
    def __instancecheck__(self, instance):
        return False

class Foo(metaclass=FalseInstance):
    pass

g = Foo()
isinstance(g, Foo)
> True
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the your non-tuple class look like? And does it implement all tuple methods that your package requires? The only real solution I can think of to your problem is subclass tuple, but override all its methods.

Comment: @Dunes Thanks, I adjusted the question. I now also understand why the code I provided doesn't work. However, if I now flip the example and change it so that `__isinstance__` always returns _True_, it still doesn't work the way I'd expect it to: `isinstance(g, int)` still returns `False`. What is the problem here?

Comment: @Dunes To your second question - `tuples` are immutable and thus a little cumbersome to use, right? I don't know yet what aspects of a tuple are required for the package to work, but I thought I'd add them whenever exceptions are thrown...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aside from the issues with `__metaclass__` and the fast-path for an exact type match, `__instancecheck__` works in the opposite direction from what you're trying to do. A class's `__instancecheck__` checks whether other objects are considered virtual instances of that class, not whether instances of that class are considered virtual instances of other classes.

If you want your objects to lie about their type in `isinstance` checks (you really shouldn't), then the way to do that is to lie about `__class__`, not implement `__instancecheck__`.

```
class BadIdea(object):
    @property
    def __class__(self):
        return tuple

print(isinstance(BadIdea(), tuple)) # prints True
```

Incidentally, if you want to get the actual type of an object, use `type` rather than checking `__class__` or `isinstance`.

Comment: Eeeek. This is indeed horrible. I wonder if it is an implementation detail that `isinstance` is fooled by this.

Comment: @jsbueno: I'm not sure. The standard library relies on it, notably in [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.__class__), but the docs for `isinstance` and `__class__` don't mention it. The [C API docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_IsInstance) mention it, but the C API is an implementation detail.

Comment: This goes directly against the PEP description, so perhaps a bug. But yes, a fast path checks for direct types first before `__instancecheck__` is called.

Comment: See [this bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue35083), there currently doesn't appear to be a consensus on whether this is a bug or documentation problem.

Answer (score 7):

If you add a print inside `FalseInstance.__instancecheck__` you will see that it is not even invoked. However, if you call `isinstance('str', Foo)` then you'll see that `FalseInstance.__instancecheck__` does get invoked.

This is due to an optimization in `isinstance`'s implementation that immediately returns `True` if `type(obj) == given_class`:

```c
int
PyObject_IsInstance(PyObject *inst, PyObject *cls)
{
    _Py_IDENTIFIER(__instancecheck__);
    PyObject *checker;

    /* Quick test for an exact match */
    if (Py_TYPE(inst) == (PyTypeObject *)cls)
        return 1;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

[From Python's source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b57b4ac042b977e0b42a2f5ddb30ca7edffacfa9/Objects/abstract.c#L2404)

Comment: Really? What's the point of even providing __isinstance__ if not to change exactly this behaviour?

Comment: it looks like in python 2.7 it did work... : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13135792/8179099

Comment: @Nearoo: `__instancecheck__` is primarily intended to make more `isinstance` checks pass, not less. Also, there's no `__isinstance__`.

Comment: However, if I now flip the example and change it so that `__isinstance__` always returns _True_, it still doesn't work the way I'd expect it to: `isinstance(g, int)` now returns `False`. What is the problem here?

Comment: @Nearoo: *There is no `__isinstance__`.* There is only `__instancecheck__`, which works in the opposite direction from what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `__instancecheck__`. But you're right, I got it the wrong way around. This clears it up, thanks a lot!!